# Potential of a charged sphere.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, physics, mathematical-physics

> Consider a charged sphere of radius $a$ and volume charge density $\rho$. Find the total work done to assemble this sphere, i.e total electric potential of this sphere.
>   Use, $$U ={1\over 8\pi} \int_{\text{Entire field}} E^2 dv$$

---

I am using cgs unit instead of SI to get rid of pesky $k$ from my equations.

Consider a sphere of arbitrary volume $v$ less than the sphere in question.

Then I got $$v = \frac43\pi r^3 \iff r = \left({3v \over 4\pi}\right)^{1/3}$$

Since $\displaystyle E = {Q\over r^2} = {\rho v\over r^2} = {\rho v^{1/3}(4\pi)^{2/3}\over 3^{2/3}}$, I got $$E^2 = {\rho^2 v^{2/3}(4\pi)^{4/3}\over 3^{4/3}} $$

Plugging this in the given equation,

$$U = {1\over 8\pi}\int^{V_f}_0 {\rho^2 v^{2/3}(4\pi)^{4/3}\over 3^{4/3}} dv$$

Where $V_f$ is the volume of the sphere in the question.

Hence I got $$U = {1\over 10}\left({4\pi\over 3}\right)^{1/3}{\rho^2v^{5/3} }$$

Since $q^2 = (\rho v)^2$, where $q$ is the total charge of the sphere,
$$U = {1\over 10} \left({4\pi\over 3}\right)^{1/3} {Q^2 \over v^{1/3}}$$

Substituting for $\displaystyle v = {4\over 3}\pi a^3$, I get,

$$U = {Q^2\over 10a}$$.

The given answer is $\displaystyle U = \frac35{Q^2 \over a}$.

I am missing a factor of $6$ in my answer. I think I messed up my limits on integral. Please help me.

Comment: The contribution to the stored energy from the field outside the sphere is $5$ times that from the interior field.  $5+1=6$ and you're done!.

Comment: @Dr.MV Yes I got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: So far, you've only included the energy due to the field inside the sphere. But there is also a field outside the sphere---specifically, $E=Q/r^2$ for $r>a$---and this must be counted if we want the total energy required to assemble the sphere. (Imagine you want to add a bit of charge to the sphere; to do so, you'll have to bring it in from infinity and therefore do work against the field outside on the way.) This gives exactly the contribution required for the final result.